# How to use audio tag of HTML 5 in IE 8?

Tags: cordova

In our application we nee dot play audio clip.We are using IE 8 browser. Please help me how to use audio tag of html5 in html without add-on.Please suggest alternate solution to play audio in IE 8 without plugin.

Thanks,

Comment: What "Cordova" tag has to do with your question ?

Comment: our application is basically phone gap windows i.e. desktop application which uses IE 8 browser.

Comment: Ok I see. Now that makes sense. But I'm afraid that you just cannot use audio tag in IE8 and earlier. Have you try an other solution if you're running your app on desktop ? (JS or/and Flash solution for example)

Comment: We need to play without any add-on. I never found any alternate solution.Tried to use embed tag but cordova file creates problem.Audio is not getting play with use of <embed> tag.

Comment: Ok. So if I understand right, you're using PhoneGap to develop a Windows app for desktop (Windows 8 I presume ?). Have you tried to you use the Media Object from PhoneGap API ?
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media